# Checking video length in moviepy without rendering it

Tags: python, moviepy

I want to create a python script what would show images for X seconds (the time until the audio goes), then go to the next image. I want the video to be X long. The lenght of the video will be always different cause of the audio. Anything that I can check the lenght of the unrendered video? My code:

```
from moviepy.editor import *

img = ['1.jpg']

clips = [ImageClip(m).set_duration(2)
      for m in img]


clip = VideoFileClip("test.mp4")
print( clip.duration )
if clip.duration > 601:
    print("clip is longer than 10 min")
else:
    print("clip is shorter than 10 min")

vid_clips = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method="compose")
vid_clips.write_videofile("test.mp4", fps=60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling the command [ffprobe](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Formatcontainerduration) would be faster than using moviepy:

```
import subprocess

def get_length(filename):
    result = subprocess.run(["ffprobe", "-v", "error", "-show_entries",
                             "format=duration", "-of",
                             "default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1", filename],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return float(result.stdout)

duration = get_length("test.mp4")
print(duration) # 30.024000
```

Comment: But to use this I have to render the video, which would be too long for me to render a video, check the lenght, if it not enough long add an image, then render it again.